# Datatable returning blank span value on date change

Tags: angularjs, datatables

Attached is the image of datatable [classroom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul4JR.jpg).

When the date is changed on no of schedules per classroom count is provided as in given picture.[classroomcount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmVoT.jpg) by default its zero.

As the td is filled with some values on changing date the td with values go blank rather than getting zero. as attached in picture [BlankColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtHHK.jpg)

Code used to get default value to zero if condition don`t match up is:

```
<td colspan="2">
 <center>
 <span>SH1</span><br>
 <span ng-init="SH1=true"></span>
 <span ng-repeat="value in classrooms">
             <span ng-if="value.classroom_name=='SH1' && value.Schedules > 0" ng-init="$parent.$parent.SH1=false">{{value.Schedules}}</span>
</span>
<span ng-if="SH1===true" style="color: red;">0</span>
</center>
</td>
```

Why is it returning blank column?